# How to dump an object that is a child of a class (knowing that class casting is impossible in Python)?

Tags: django, django-models

I have a 3 models: `Entity`, `Person` which is a child of `Entity`, and `Agenda`:

```
class Entity(models.Model):
    is_physical = models.BooleanField(default=True)

class Person(Entity):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, blank=True, null=True,
                                on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    agendas = models.ManyToManyField('Agenda')
    def simple_desc(self):
        return str(self.user) if self.user is not None else '? no user ?'

class Agenda(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(Entity, blank=True, null=True,
                              on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                              related_name='owner')
```

You (almost) can't do simpler!

Now I would like to list all the owners of all the agendas *starting with agendas* like:

```
for agenda in Agenda.objects.all():
    print(agenda.owner.simple_desc())
```

Because `owner` is an `Entity`, it doesn't know about `simple_desc()` (which is in its child `Person`). It's impossible to cast the `owner` into a `Person`. How would you do?

Note aside:

- Right now, all `owner` are `Person`, but in a near futur, I'll create `Company(Entity)` which could also be `owner` of an `Agenda`, so I need to keep my models like this, don't suggest to change this organization this is not a valid solution.
- It's important, I have a more complex query, to make my loop with `Agenda` (and not `Person`)

Comment: What do you mean with *starting with agendas*?

Comment: There's a one-to-one relationship between the two instances that Django creates behind the scenes. So `agenda.owner.person` gives you the person object (you should check if the attribute exists, if the `owner` is a `Company` this will throw an `AttributeError`)

Comment: My bad, @WillemVanOnsem is correct, it throws a `DoesNotExist` error. [Here's](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/models/#multi-table-inheritance) the reference.

Comment: @dirkgoten: it is an `AttributeError` as well, the MRO is `<class 'core.models.Entity.DoesNotExist'>, <class 'django.core.exceptions.ObjectDoesNotExist'>, <class 'AttributeError'>, <class 'Exception'>, <class 'BaseException'>, <class 'object'>` (so it is a merge of a `DoesNotExist`, and an `AttributeError`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Person` has an (implicit) `OneToOneField` to `Entity`, so you can obtain the person with:

```
for agenda in Agenda.objects.all():
    try:
        print(agenda.owner.person.simple_desc())
    except Person.DoesNotExist:
        pass
```

It will raise a `Person.DoeNotExist` in case the `Entity` has no related `Person` object.